# When change view into rendered, the object turning grey.

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have followed this tutorial recently:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLUAp4lSxLI

But I had the problem at 30:12. When he changed viewport into rendered, the object is clear:[image]

However, I did the same as he did, but my object looks grey:
[image]

Had I skipped something important?? What's that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the previous videos he had assigned an HDR image as a light source.

In the world panel click the button right of the dark grey colored box
[image]

Then choose environment texture
[image]

Then load Your HDR image:

[image]

You can find these HDR images for free at [HDRIhaven](https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/)
An HDR image is basically a spheric image with awesome light information

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried and the problem solved. You really help me. And thanks for providing free HDR images website :)

Comment: @C.Mar No problem:-)

Comment: By the way, is it necessary to use HDR images for objects?

Comment: @C.Mar No not at all! It is just a very easy method to get a realistic light setup. You can add other light sources, Sun lamp, spot lamp, point lamp or make a emmisive material and assign object, to make them light sources! Check this video for a run down of the basics https://youtu.be/m-N149FMlWk

Comment: Oh, thank you for answering my questions and sharing the tutorial. Now I understand how to make light! I'm new to blender and still learning from others video. Your answers really help me. Wish you have a nice day!